# OnClickListener doesn't work in a JSON Poulated ListView

Tags: android, json, listview, onitemclicklistener

I work with a ListView populated by a JSON, this part works, but when I have clicked on a list item, the click doesn't work.

I have read things about 
`setDescendantFocusability(FOCUS_BLOCK_DESCENDANTS);` But I don't understand where to put that.

**Here is my code**

This a fragment displayed in a TabLayout in MainActivity

```
public class Tab3 extends Fragment {
private View v;

private  ListView listView;
private ArrayList<CustomModel> mCustomArrayList = new ArrayList<CustomModel>();

private AdapterCustom adapter1;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    String equipeJSONString=((MainActivity)getActivity()).equipeJSONString;

    try {

        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(equipeJSONString);
        JSONArray equipe = obj.getJSONArray("equipe");

          for (int i = 0; i < equipe.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject c = equipe.getJSONObject(i);
            //stock les valeurs du Json dans des vars
            String nom = c.getString("nom");
            String photo = c.getString("photo");
            String texte = c.getString("texte");
            mCustomArrayList.add(new CustomModel(nom, texte,photo));

         }

    } catch (Throwable t) {
        Log.e("Tab3", "Erreur Could not parse malformed JSON : \"" + equipeJSONString + "\"");
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    v =inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_3,container,false);
  //  v.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);      

    listView = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.customlist);

    adapter1 = new AdapterCustom(getActivity(), mCustomArrayList);
    // Assign adapter to ListView
    listView.setAdapter(adapter1);

    // ListView Item Click Listener
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,     int position, long id) {
            Log.v("Tab3","click on Item");

            // ListView Clicked item index
            int itemPosition     = position;

            // ListView Clicked item value
            String  itemValue    = (String) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);

            // Show Alert
           Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                    "Position :" + itemPosition + "  ListItem : " + itemValue, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();

            Intent myIntent = new Intent(getActivity(),CustomActivity.class);                
            startActivity(myIntent);
    }
    });

     return v;
    }
  }
```

**Edit : I have done a test with String[]**

If I use a String[] to populate the list it works, I can click.

Code tested on OnCreateView :

```
    String[] values2 = new String[] { "Android List View",
            "Adapter implementation",
            "Simple List View In Android",
            "Create List View Android",
            "Android Example",
            "List View Source Code",
            "List View Array Adapter",
            "Android Example List View"
    };
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, values2);
```

So what is wrong when I populate with my AdapterCustom ?

Comment: Inside `onCreateView` call `listView.setDescendantFocusability(FOCUS_BLOCK_DESCENDANTS);`

Comment: Ok, but when I add it I have this error : `codeError:(101, 44) error: cannot find symbol variable FOCUS_BLOCK_DESCENDANTS` and I can't add an automatic import

Comment: Yes, it should be `ViewGroup.FOCUS_BLOCK_DESCENDANTS` - forgot it.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but i- does not work better, I still do not have the log for the click

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I have found, I had a

```
.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
```

in my `CustomAdapter` that handled the click.

Making those tests helped me to find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
listView.setClickable(true);//in fragment

@Override
public boolean isEnabled(int position) //in adapter
{
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use a switch case inside `onItemClick`
like

```
switch(position)
{
case 0:

String  itemValue    = (String) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);

            // Show Alert
           Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                    "Position :" + itemPosition + "  ListItem : " + itemValue, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();

            Intent myIntent = new Intent(getActivity(),CustomActivity.class);

            startActivity(myIntent);


}
```

Comment: In my case I do not have the Log.v("Tab3","click on Item"); on the log, so I think the problem is not here.